# Return older files by date

Tags: perl, file, perl-module, directory, mod-perl

I have the following files in a directory, where the delimiter is "_" and the third field is the date when the file was created. 
Now I need to always pick the file that has the earliest date in accordance with the first column code.

Example:

```
1020300000_XXXXXXXXX_20160707193000.TXT
1020300000_XXXXXXXXX_20160707170000.TXT
1020400000_XXXXXXXXX_20160707180000.TXT
1020400000_XXXXXXXXX_20160707190000.TXT
```

In this case I need to have as a result the older files.

```
1020300000_XXXXXXXXX_20160707170000.TXT
1020400000_XXXXXXXXX_20160707180000.TXT
```

Could someone help me return only the older files?

Comment: Why `1020300000_XXXXXXXXX_20160707193000.TXT` is older than `1020300000_XXXXXXXXX_20160707170000.TXT`? Is the directory listing already sorted by date? Aren't the last 6 digits HHMMSS?

Comment: @LeonardoBerbert - can please answer the Casimir's question

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $path = "./yourdir";
opendir (my $dh, $path) || die "Can't opendir $path: $!";

my @filelist = grep { -f "$path/$_" } readdir $dh;

my @result = sort values {        # (4)
    map +( $_->[1], $_->[0] ),    # (3) 
    sort { $b->[2] cmp $a->[2] }  # (2)
    map [ $_, (split '_')[0,2] ], # (1)
 @filelist
};

say join "\n", @result;
```

<sup>(1) *return a list of references to anonymous three elements arrays:*

([filename, firstpart, thirdpart], [filename, firstpart, thirdpart], ...)</sup>
<sub>(2) *return a sorted list in descending order (from newest to oldest) using the creation date (thirdpart).*</sub>

<sup>(3) *return a list consisting of the "firstpart" and the* "filename" *from each array referenced in the input list:*

                                  (firstpart, filename, firstpart, filename, ...)</sup>
<sub>(4) *An anonymous hash is created with the list (here curly brackets don't delimit a block or an expression but define a hash). All* firstpart*s become the keys and all* filename*s the values.
Since filenames was previously sorted from newest to oldest, each key is in fine associated with the oldest filename that overwrites eventual more recent previous values for the same key.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact the the date is in YYYYMMDDHHMISS and just sort them and use a hash to only get the top value, returning the entries that you need:

```
sub get_oldest_two {
    my (@files) = @_;

    my @sorted = sort { [split(/_/, $a)]->[2] lt [split(/_/, $b)]->[2] } @files;
    my %file_dates = map { [split(/_/, $_)]->[0] => $_ } @sorted;
    return reverse(sort((values(%file_dates))[0..1]));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume your output should be

```
1020300000_XXXXXXXXX_20160707170000.TXT
1020400000_XXXXXXXXX_20160707180000.TXT
```

. If not, I don't know what your requirement is. Anyway I hope this is what you need

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;

# folder saves the files
$folder = "test";

# save file names as array
@files = `ls $folder`;
chomp @files;

foreach $file (@files){
        #split filename to 3 columns e.g.
        #1020300000 XXXXXXXXX 20160707170000.TXT
        ($col_1, $col_2, $col_3) = split(/_/, $file);

        #delete .TXT
        $col_3 =~ s/\.txt$//i;

        #use my to create new @tmp every loop
        my @tmp = ($col_3, $file);

        #%outpput is our target result
        #col_1 is key, the hash should look like this
        #  '1020300000' => [
        #                    '20160707170000',  <= this is col_3, will be used to compare later
        #                    '1020300000_XXXXXXXXX_20160707170000.TXT'  <= condidate of the result
        #                  ]
        unless(defined $output{$col_1}){
                $output{$col_1} = \@tmp;
                next;
        };

        $saved_col_3 = $output{$col_1}->[0];

        #because $col_1 are the same (key), so compare their col_3 value
        if($col_3 < $saved_col_3){
                #update if this one is smaller
                $output{$col_1} = \@tmp;
        }
}

#print Dumper(\%output);

#so....
foreach (keys %output){
        print "$output{$_}->[1]\n";
}
```